# Child to parent communication in React on Asp.net core 2.0

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a React app (not ReactJs) in asp.net core 2.0 that I'm having a problem with.  I have a child component that needs to communicate with the parent.  Specifically when a button in the child component is clicked I need to relay that to the parent.  Here's what I've got but I can't quite make it work...

child component:

```js
export class Buttons extends React.Component<any, any> {

  buttonClick(idx) {
    //I would like to notify parent component here
    //that Button (idx) was clicked
    return idx
  }

  public render() {
    return <div>
        <button onClick={this.buttonClick}>Button 1</button>
        <button onClick={this.buttonClick}>Button 2</button>
        <button onClick={this.buttonClick}>Button 3</button>
        <button onClick={this.buttonClick}>Button 4</button>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

parent component:

```js
export class Home extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {

  ...
  handler(idx) {
    //need idx here
  }

  return <div>
        {content}
        <h1>Buttons</h1>
        <Buttons buttonClick={this.handler} />
    </div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 main options here,
Easy solution but considered a **bad practice**.
A bit more complex but considered **good practice**.

- **The easy solution:**
  use currying to pass a parameter of `id` to the handler:
  This is  bad practice as it will create a new instance of a function
  on each render, which may lead to performance issues as you pass new prop on each render and this can interrupt the [diffing algorithm of react](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html).

  ```js
     
     class Buttons extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
         super(props);
     
         this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this);
       }
       
       buttonClick(idx) {
         const that = this;
         return function (e) {
           that.props.buttonClick(idx);
         }
       }
     
       render() {
         return <div>
           <button onClick={this.buttonClick(1)}>Button 1</button>
           <button onClick={this.buttonClick(2)}>Button 2</button>
           <button onClick={this.buttonClick(3)}>Button 3</button>
           <button onClick={this.buttonClick(4)}>Button 4</button>
         </div>;
       }
     }
     
     
     class App extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {};
     
         this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
       }
     
       handler(idx) {
         console.log(idx);
       }
     
       render() {
         return (
           <div>
             <h1>Buttons</h1>
             <Buttons buttonClick={this.handler} />
           </div>
         );
       }
     }
     
     ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
  ```

  ```html
     
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
     <div id="root"></div>
  ```
- **The better solution:**
  Use a component to handle the `id` and pass it upwards to the handler.
  This is good practice as your are using component composition which can let you reuse code, test it and better maintain and debug it, plus you don't have the performance issue when you create new instances on each render.

  ```js
     
     class MyButton extends React.Component{
       constructor(props) {
         super(props);
     
         this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this);
       }
       buttonClick(idx) {
           this.props.buttonClick(this.props.buttonId);
       }
     
       render(){
         return(
           <button onClick={this.buttonClick}>{this.props.children}</button>
         );
       }
     }
     
     class Buttons extends React.Component {
     
       render() {
         return <div>
           <MyButton buttonClick={this.props.buttonClick} buttonId={1}>Button 1</MyButton>
           <MyButton buttonClick={this.props.buttonClick} buttonId={2}>Button 2</MyButton>
           <MyButton buttonClick={this.props.buttonClick} buttonId={3}>Button 3</MyButton>
           <MyButton buttonClick={this.props.buttonClick} buttonId={4}>Button 4</MyButton>
         </div>;
       }
     }
     
     
     class App extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {};
     
         this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
       }
     
       handler(idx) {
         console.log(idx);
       }
     
       render() {
         return (
           <div>
             <h1>Buttons</h1>
             <Buttons buttonClick={this.handler} />
           </div>
         );
       }
     }
     
     ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
  ```

  ```html
     
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
     <div id="root"></div>
  ```

Comment: Thx a bunch...I was banging my head on the wall over this

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in your child component:

```js
export default class Buttons extends React.Component {

  buttonClick = (idx) => {
    this.props.buttonClick(idx);
  }

  public render() {
    return <div>
        <button onClick={this.buttonClick(1)}>Button 1</button>
        <button onClick={this.buttonClick(2)}>Button 2</button>
        <button onClick={this.buttonClick(3)}>Button 3</button>
        <button onClick={this.buttonClick(4)}>Button 4</button>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: this won't work as your are not passing a function reference but the returned value of the function (which is undefined by the way as this function doesn't return anything)

Comment: oh right.  duh.  that's what I get for not testing first.  looks like someone posted a better answer so I'm not going to bother fixing.